# how to identify and read if this is hex or some other string?

Tags: php, hex

Any ideas what this might be or how i can read it? I thought it might be hex but using standard Hex to ascii converters it doesn't yield anything meaningful.

The label of this was 'Log ID' so I am assuming it should convert to some sort of serial number or ID.

`A4:B9:09:90:B4:18:58:14:87:BB:13:A2:CC:67:70:0A:3C:35:98:04:F9:1B:DF:B8:E3:77:CD:0E:C8:0D:DC:10`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-xdigit.php

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I need to use hex to base64 to get the correct conversion.. can be tested here: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

It is a SHA-256 hash of the log's public key, which is used in CT extension of signed TLS certificate. There is nothing meaningful(at least not human-readable) and it is not related to php at all.